# Basic HTTP Authentication over HTTPS with WCF

Tags: wcf, https, basic-authentication

I’m calling a web service via WCF (w/ .NET 4.0) that requires basic HTTP authentication (with username and password.) over HTTPS.  While, I think I’ve got everything setup correctly, I’m getting a 401 error whenever I make the call to the service.  I monitored the HTTP traffic and noticed that WCF seems to be ignoring that I told it to use an authorization header with the username and password, as none is sent in the request.  Here’s my configuration below.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

```
   <system.serviceModel>
         <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                       <binding name="BasicAuthSecured">
                             <security mode="Transport">
                                    <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
                             </security>
                       </binding>
                       </basicHttpBinding>
                </bindings>
         <client>
                <endpoint address="https://REMOVED FOR CONFIDENTIALITY"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicAuthSecured"
            contract="Five9.WsAdmin" name="WsAdminPort" />
         </client>
         <behaviors>
                <serviceBehaviors>
                       <behavior name="">
                             <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                             <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                       </behavior>
                </serviceBehaviors>
         </behaviors>
   </system.serviceModel>
```

And here’s my code:

```
        var five_9_client = new WsAdminClient();

        five_9_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = “REMOVED FOR CONFIDENTIALITY";
        five_9_client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "REMOVED FOR CONFIDENTIALITY";

        var call_log_response = five_9_client.getCallLogReport(call_log); //Bombing out here
```

I’m getting this exception:

{"The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was ''."}

With inner exception:

{"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."}

With stack trace:

at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateAuthentication(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, WebException responseException, HttpChannelFactory factory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ValidateRequestReplyResponse(HttpWebRequest request, HttpWebResponse response, HttpChannelFactory factory, WebException responseException, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Comment: Are you using `basicHttpBinding` over `WSHttpBinding` because you need to support SOAP 1.1 clients?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the solution:  basically, the problem was that the header had to be attached to the current request, like so:

```
      var base_64_encoded_credentials =
            BasicHTTPAuthenticationEncoder.base_64_encode_credentials(
                client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName, client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password);

        HttpRequestMessageProperty request = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
        request.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + base_64_encoded_credentials;

        OperationContextScope clientScope = new OperationContextScope(five_9_client.InnerChannel);
        OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add(HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name, request);
```

Comment: `string base_64_encoded_credentials = System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the problem is that you have not set the client credential type, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731925.aspx

Either it is not being sent at all, or the default client credential type does not send the credentials in the header.

Comment: After monitoring with Fiddler, it does not look as if it is being sent at all.  Could it be that WCF does not append the HTTP authorization header before sending the https request?